# Mergesort: How does the computational complexity vary when changing the split point?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, big-o, mergesort

I have to do an exercise from my algorithm book. Suppose a mergesort is implemented to split an array by α, which is in a range from 0.1 to 0.9.

This is the original method to calculate the split point

```
middle = fromIndex + (toIndex - fromIndex)/2;
```

I would like to change it to this:

```
factor = 0.1; //varies in range from 0.1 to 0.9
middle = fromIndex + (toIndex - fromIndex)*factor;
```

So my questions are:

1. Does this impact the computational complexity?
2. What's the impact on recursion tree depths?

Comment: The algorithm is still linearithmic, but the tree does get deeper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does change the actual complexity, but not the asymptotic complexity.

If you think about the new recurrence relation you'll get, it will be

> T(1) = 1
>
> T(n) = T(αn) + T((1 - α)n) + Θ(n)

Looking over the recursion tree, each level of the tree still has a total of Θ(n) work per level, but the number of levels will be greater.  Specifically, let's suppose that 0.5 ≤ α < 1.  Then after k recursive calls, the size of the smallest block remaining in the recursion will have size n α<sup>k</sup>.  The recurrence stops when this hits size one.  Solving, we get:

> n α<sup>k</sup> = 1
>
> α <sup>k</sup> = 1/n
>
> k log α = -log n
>
> k = -log n / log α
>
> k = log n / log (1/α)

In other words, varying α varies the constant factor on the logarithmic term of the depth of the recursion.  The above equation is minimized when α = 0.5 (since we are subject to the restriction that α ≥ 0.5), so this would be the optimal way to split.  However, picking other splits still gives runtime Θ(n log n), though with a higher constant term.

Hope this helps!